# Beam radiation tilt factor calculation

Tags: python, numpy, pvlib

I want to calculate total solar irradiance using isotropic sky model.

My problem is calculation of `Rb` (beam radiation tilt factor) in which I reach some negative values which is nonsense.

Formula:

```
Rb = cos⁡(angle_of_incidence)/cos⁡(solar_zenith)
```

Code in Python:

```
Rb = np.cos(pvlib.irradiance.aoi(surface_tilt, surface_azimuth, solar_zenith, solar_azimuth))/np.cos(solar_zenith)
```

Could you help me to solve negative values in `Rb`?

(My reference: Solar Energy Engineering: Processes and Systems, Soteris A. Kalogirou)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows your problem

Comment: Either the numerator or denominator has an angle > pi/2 in the argument. Which one is it? Did you forget to convert the output of a library function from degrees to radians?

Comment: I guess I've been doing this long enough  :). A *very* cursory inspection of the docs shows that my gut guess was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only way your fraction could be negative is if either the numerator or denominator were negative. For cosines, that only happens if the argument is greater than `π/2`.

When dealing with trig function problems, the most likely culprit is conversation from degrees to radians (or lack thereof). And it's spelled out in the [docs](https://wholmgren-pvlib-python-new.readthedocs.io/en/doc-reorg2/generated/irradiance/pvlib.irradiance.aoi.html):

> **Returns:**  **aoi** : numeric
>
> Angle of incidence in degrees.

To fix the immediate problem:

```
R_b = np.cos(pvlib.irradiance.aoi(surface_tilt, surface_azimuth, solar_zenith, solar_azimuth) * np.pi / 180.0)/np.cos(solar_zenith)
```

Since you don't show the origin of `solar_zenith`, I can't tell you if it needs to be converted too.

And don't forget:

> Input all angles in degrees.

Comment: Hi Mad Physicist, Thank you for the comments. From https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/641 I understood that when the sun is behind the plane `Rb` is negative.

Comment: @Mohi. Yes that's true, but it doesn't alter the fact that you're passing in a quantity in degrees to a function that accepts radians

Comment: @Mohi. Put it another way, negative angles make sense physically, but the numbers you're going to get without the conversion are going to be wrong regardless.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I corrected it. Thank you for your clarification.